# Bulk remove 1 second from end of MP3s

Tags: audio, mp3, audiobook

I have an mp3 audiobook and each track has exactly 1 second of static at the end. Is there a way to bulk cut out last second from each track?

Comment: @Moab: trimming silence isn't necessarily the same as trimming noise or trimming a set time.  Do the answers on the proposed duplicate solve the issue here?

Comment: Yes they did. The application referenced has an option to trim arbitrary length from beginning or end.